# Detect a ReactList's scroll, running under Angular 15

Tags: reactjs, angular

I need to detect when a ReactList scrolls, (when it applies the transform: translate() to the list, how do I trap this event? The React component is created under Angular 15 (I cannot remove the React component and replace it with a cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport or any other list vrtualisation).

Comment: Giving some code examples will help you get an answer